# como imprimir tabela em duas colunas?

Tags: vba, impressora, print

Tenho uma tabela com mais linhas que cabem em uma página A4, mas, se dividida em duas podem ser impressas em uma página, com duas colunas.
Já consultei outros sites e obtive ajuda, mas não resolveu.
Anexo o código que utilizei em minha tentativa.
Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço muito.

```
`Sub ImprimeLista()

'Imprime Lista do Mercado

Dim BlocPrint As Range
Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastCol As Integer
  
    Sheets("Compras").Select
  
    Cells(1, 1).Select
  
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    FirstRow = Selection.Row
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row
  
    Set BlocPrint = Range(Cells(FirstRow, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        BlocPrint.Select
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 2
        Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
        Range("A1").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Oi Bautto! Como vai? Por favor, poderia inserir uma imagem mostrando como a sua planilha está estruturada, indicando, principalmente, qual é a última linha preenchida para que eu possa te ajudar? Obrigada!

Comment: Olá, Andréa. Segue o link para o arquivo.

Comment: Nele tem 2 planilhas, a primeira (Tabelão) é a entrada de dados e a segunda(Compras) é a que preciso imprimir, que resume os itens a serem comprados. Agradeço seu interesse. https://www.sendspace.com/file/ivezqi

Comment: Oi! Eu testei o código na planilha que você me enviou e a tabela foi impressa em uma única página. Eu testei duas vezes: na primeira eu não alterei as configurações padrão da impressão e, na segunda, eu alterei e nos dois casos o resultado foi o mesmo. Você esperava algum resultado diferente? https://www.sendspace.com/file/zula7n

Comment: A impressão sai em uma única página. O que quero é que saia em duas colunas, pois em uma só fica muito reduzida a impressão, dificultando a leitura. Estou tentando fazer uma rotina para dividir a impressão, por exemplo, imprimir as primeiras 60 linhas em uma coluna e as restantes em outra, mas estou encontrando dificuldade na configuração da impressora pelo VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Oi!

Eu fiz uma leve gambiarra, mas acredito que traz o resultado desejado.

Como, pela configuração da impressão, não é possível ajeita para que imprima duas colunas, a minha ideia foi criar uma aba auxiliar em que a lista de compras seja copiada e impressa tal como desejado.

Segue o código:

```
Sub ImprimeLista()

'Imprime Lista do Mercado

Dim BlocPrint As Range
Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim W       As Worksheet
Dim WB      As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Sheets("Compras").Select
    
    Cells(1, 1).Select
  
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    FirstRow = Selection.Row
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row
  
       
    'Adiciona uma nova aba e copia a tabela para ela
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Impressão"
    Set WB = Sheets("Impressão")
    Set W = Sheets("Compras")
    
    W.Select
    
    'Seleciona a primeira metade
    Set BlocPrint = W.Range(Cells(FirstRow, 1), Cells((LastRow / 2), LastCol))
    BlocPrint.Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Select
    WB.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
    'Seleciona a segunda metade
    W.Select
    Set BlocPrint = W.Range(Cells((LastRow / 2), 1), Cells((LastRow), LastCol))
    BlocPrint.Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Select
    WB.Range("G4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Coloca um cabeçalho na segunda coluna
    WB.Range("A1:E3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Range("G1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1:E1").Select
    
    'Ajeita as colunas com produtos
    WB.Range("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    WB.Range("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    WB.Columns(6).ColumnWidth = 2
   
   
  'Configura a impressão
   With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        WB.Select
        WB.Range("A:G").Select
'        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
        Range("A1").Select
    End With
    
    'Seleciona a planilha Compras e exclui a planilha Impressão
    W.Select
    W.Range("A1").Select
    WB.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

O resultado final foi esse: https://www.sendspace.com/file/6psv97

Espero que resolva.

Comment: Andréa, bom dia. Gostei muito de sua solução, principalmente por usar o VBA. Eu já tinha arrumado também uma alternativa, porém o que fiz foi bem manual, transcrevendo a fórmula que compila a lista para a outra metade da planilha, e dividindo as linhas, sem programação VBA. Resolveu também, mas seu trabalho ficou ótimo. Grato pelo auxílio.